# NotifyItemRemoved shows the animation but the item remains inside. Does not get removed

Tags: android, animation, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a queue, in which I add items when I swipe them. And then I go through it, and I want to remove the items I swiped, with an animation, using notifyItemRemoved.
This is my code:

```
   public void goThroughRemovalQueue() {
    Log.i("#tagTimelineTrip", "goThroughRemovalQueue handleResponseInTransactionTags goThroughRemovalQueue: " + ids.size());
    if (!removingTrip) {
        if (ids != null && ids.size() > 0) {
            removingTrip = true;
            boolean found = false;
            final RemovalAnimationQueueModel obj = ids.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
                if (obj.getId().equals(mItems.get(i).getId())) {
                    found = true;
                    obj.setPosition(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                Log.e("#tagTimelineTrip", "handleResponseInTransactionTags position: " + obj.getPosition() + " tabType: " + obj.getLastTab());
                mItems.remove(obj.getPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(obj.getPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(obj.getPosition(), mItems.size());
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        removingTrip = false;
                        goThroughRemovalQueue();
                    }
                }, delayRemovalAnimation);
            } else {
                removingTrip = false;
            }
            setIsTagging(obj.getViewHolder().swipeLayout, false, obj.getViewHolder().container);
            obj.getViewHolder().greenView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ids.remove(0);
        } else {
            removingTrip = false;
            back.onResponse(Constants.TIMELINE_CALLBACK_REFRESH);
        }
    } else new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            goThroughRemovalQueue();
        }
    }, delayRemovalAnimation);
}
```

For now I am trying it just for 1 object, so I can make sure that it works on 1 item in the queue. But the item is being removed, with an animation and then it appears back, why is that happening?

Video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rxjeg5sdx7ed5a/video-1517397768.mp4?dl=0

Comment: try this `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mItems.size()- obj.getPosition());`

Comment: what returns getPosition ? [int or Integer?](https://ideone.com/1dX3tD)

Comment: @Selvin Excellent notice

Comment: It was easy ... code looks ok -  the only possibility was *`mItems.remove` doesn't work* :) ... If I would debug this code I would log `mItems` size at the very first place .... anyway in C# there would be no problem ... Java's generics are f**ed up...

Comment: @Selvin Knowledge + experience = priceless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still tweaking it, but I think I found the issue:

```
 mItems.remove(obj.getPosition());
```

Even though obj.getPosition is a Integer.
`mItems.remove(obj.getPosition())` would take it as an Object, so it would try to remove an object similar to that Integer.
By casting to int, now it removes the object from that position:
`mItems.remove((int)obj.getPosition());`